# How to find the maximum of this function by observation: ${f}(x)=-124 \cos (x^{2})x^{2}-62 \sin (x^{2})$

Tags: calculus, functions

How to find the maximum of this function by **observation** (without graphing)?
${f}(x)=-124 \cos (x^{2})x^{2}-62 \sin (x^{2})$

**Using the fact that cos(x) and sin(x) is between -1 and 1.**

Comment: [Helpful graph](http://i.imgur.com/x9oFyBV.png)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing description. By observation, I mean using the fact that cos(x) and sin(x) is between -1 and 1.

Comment: Are you sure you have the question right?  That doesn't look bounded.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not ${f}(x)=-124 \cos (x^{2})-62 \sin (x^{2})$ instead ? Otherwise, $\infty$. Or, is $x$ limited to a range ?

Comment: Yes, for sure, but I cannot find the max. by using the fact.